# Функция похожих записей Wordpress. Как добавить текст, заголовок

Tags: wordpress

Есть функция для вывода в записи ссылок на другие записи из этой рубрики:

```
/**
 * Предыдущие записи из рубрики (относительно текущей записи) +
 * кольцевая перелинковка (можно указывать таксономию и тип записи).
 *
 * Кэширует результат в объектный кэш, если он включен.
 *
 * Вызываем функцию так:
 *
 *     echo kama_previous_posts_from_tax_lis( [
 *         'post_num' => 5,
 *         'format' => '{date:j.M.Y} - {a}{title}{/a}',
 *     ] );
 *
 * @param array|string $args {
 *     Parameters passed as array or query string.
 *
 *     @type int    $post_num  Количество ссылок.
 *     @type string $format    {thumb} {date:j.M.Y} - {a}{title}{/a} ({comments})
 *     @type string $list_tag  Тег-обертка каждой ссылки.
 *     @type string $tax       Таксономия. пр. category.
 *     @type string $post_type Тип записи. пр. post.
 * }
 *
 * @version 1.2
 */
function kama_previous_posts_from_tax_lis( $args = array() ){
    global $post, $wpdb;

    $rg = (object) wp_parse_args( $args, [
        'post_num'  => 5,
        'format'    => '',
        'list_tag'  => 'li',
        'tax'       => 'category',
        'post_type' => 'post',
    ] );

    if( wp_using_ext_object_cache() ){
        $cache_key = md5( __FUNCTION__ . $post->ID );
        $cache_flag = __FUNCTION__;

        if( $cache_out = wp_cache_get( $cache_key, $cache_flag ) ){
            return $cache_out;
        }
    }

    $SELECT = "SELECT ID, post_title, post_date, comment_count, guid
        FROM $wpdb->posts p
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships rel ON (p.ID = rel.object_id)
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tax ON (rel.term_taxonomy_id = tax.term_taxonomy_id)";

    $WHERE = $wpdb->prepare( 'WHERE p.post_date < %s', $post->post_date );

    $sub_query_tax_id = $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT term_id FROM $wpdb->term_relationships rl
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tx ON (rl.term_taxonomy_id = tx.term_taxonomy_id)
            WHERE object_id = %d AND tx.taxonomy = %s
            LIMIT 1",
        $post->ID, $rg->tax
    );

    $AND = $wpdb->prepare("
        AND tax.term_id = ($sub_query_tax_id) AND tax.taxonomy = %s
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
        AND p.post_type = %s ORDER BY p.post_date DESC",
        $rg->tax, $rg->post_type
    );

    $LIMIT = 'LIMIT ' . (int) $rg->post_num;
    $sql = "$SELECT $WHERE $AND $LIMIT";

    $res = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );

    $count_res = count( $res );

    // если количество меньше нужного, делаем 2-й запрос (кольцевая перелинковка)
    if( ! $res || $count_res < $rg->post_num ){
        $NOT_IN = $post->ID;
        foreach( $res as $id ){
            $NOT_IN .= ",$id->ID";
        }
        $sql = "$SELECT WHERE p.ID NOT IN ($NOT_IN) $AND LIMIT " . (int) ( $rg->post_num - $count_res );

        $res2 = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );

        $res = array_merge( $res, $res2 );
    }

    if( ! $res ){
        return '';
    }

    // вывод
    if( $rg->format ){
        preg_match( '!{date:(.*?)}!', $rg->format, $date_m );
    }

    $add_thumb = false !== strpos( $rg->format, '{thumb}' );

    $out = '';
    foreach( $res as $pst ){
        $x = ( @ $x === 'li1' ) ? 'li2' : 'li1';

        $a = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $pst->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $pst->post_title ) . '">';

        if( $rg->format ){
            $formated = strtr( $rg->format, [
                '{title}'    => esc_html( $pst->post_title ),
                '{a}'        => $a,
                '{/a}'       => '</a>',
                '{comments}' => $pst->comment_count ?: '',
                '{thumb}' => $add_thumb ? str_replace( '{thumb}', get_the_post_thumbnail( $pst->ID, 'thumbnail' ), $formated ) : '',
            ] );

            // есть дата
            if( $date_m ){
                $formated = str_replace( $date_m[0], apply_filters( 'the_time', mysql2date( $date_m[1], $pst->post_date ) ), $formated );
            }
        }
        else{
            $formated = $a . esc_html( $pst->post_title ) . '</a>';
        }

        $out .= "\t<li class=\"$x\">$formated</li>\n";
    }

    if( wp_using_ext_object_cache() ){
        wp_cache_add( $cache_key, $out, $cache_flag );
    }

    return $out;
}
```

https://wp-kama.ru/id_275/perelinkovka-statey-v-wordpress-predyiduschie-zapisi-iz-kategorii-funktsiya-2.html

В шаблоне потом выводится так:

```
<?php echo kama_previous_posts_from_tax('post_num=10'); ?>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как туда добавить заголовок. Типа "Похожие записи". То есть, чтобы он выводился, только если есть другие записи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо строки

```
 $out = '';
```

```
 $out = $res ? 'Ваш заголовок' : '';
```